# list index out of range error in python , why does it happen?

Tags: python-3.x, list

''' Read input from STDIN. Print your output to STDOUT '''
    #Use input() to read input from STDIN and use print to write your output to STDOUT

def main():

```
t = int(input())
strr =[]
vcount =0
ccount =0
for i in range(t):
    s = input()
    strr[i].append(s)
for i in strr:
    for j in i:
        if j == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
            vcount += 1
        else:
            ccount +=1
    print(vcount,ccount,vcount*ccount)
```

main()

## error while uploading into strr, plz correct the code

Comment: Please give a [mre]. But you've definitely made this common error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/3001761, and you seem to be trying to index into *an empty list*.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably will not through that error

```
t = int(input())
strr =[]
vcount =0
ccount =0
for i in range(t):
    s = input()
    strr.append(s)
for i in strr:
    for j in i:
        if j == 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
            vcount += 1
        else:
            ccount +=1
    print(vcount,ccount,vcount*ccount)
```